# Is $n^K*2^n$ in $O(3^n)$?

Tags: asymptotics, exponential-function

I need to prove or disprove that $n^K⋅2^n$ is in $O(3^n)$, $K$ being a constant $>0$. 
I suspect logarithms will be involved, moreover I suspect that $n^K⋅2^n$ is indeed in $O(3^n)$, but do not know how to reason from there. Please help!

Edit: I use the following definition for the big O: $f(n) ∈ O(g(n)) \equiv \{\exists k>0\;\exists n_{0}\;\forall n>n_{0}\;|f(n)|\leq k\cdot g(n)\}$

Comment: Be sure to specifiy all of your symbols and definitions, please!

Comment: What's the definition of big O notation? What do you need to prove? Why didn't you already prove this?

Comment: So $n^K \cdot 2^n$ is the number of operations required to accomplish something?

Comment: Here's an alternate approach. Do you agree that $n^K \in O((3/2)^n)$? You should, since $n^K$ grows polynomially and $(3/2)^n$ grows exponentially. Now multiply both sides of $n^K \in O((3/2)^n)$ by $2^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume $K>0^, otherwise it is trivial.

If $f(n)\in O(3^n)$ then there exists a constant $\varepsilon>0$ and a natural $M$ such that for all $n>M$, $f(n)<\varepsilon\cdot 3^n$.

Hence in your case:

$n^K\cdot 2^n=e^{n\cdot\ln 2+K\ln n}<e^{n\ln 3+\ln c}$

which holds true if

$n\cdot\ln 2+K\ln n<n\ln 3+\ln c$

rearranging...

$K\ln n<n(\ln 3-\ln 2)+\ln c$

and hence

$\ln n<n\frac{\ln\frac{3}{2}}{K}+\frac1{K}\cdot\ln c$

which holds always true for big enough $n$.